# std::tuple<> of one std::shared_ptr<> does not work?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic, reference-counting

I recently discovered a problem with using `std::tuple<>` for just one element. I created a class for type erasure and retaining N number of reference counted objects. However the reference counted object is not retained if it is the only one in the `std::tuple<>`.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
class token {
public:
  template<typename... Types>
  token(Types... types) : _self(std::make_shared<const std::tuple<Types...>>(std::make_tuple(std::move(types)...))) {}

  // Why do I need this special version of the constructor?
  // Uncomment and the code will work!
  //template<typename T>
  //token(T t) : _self(std::make_shared<const T>(std::move(t))) {}
private:
  std::shared_ptr<const void> _self;
};
```

Example (tested with Xcode 8.0):

```
token make_token() {
  std::shared_ptr<int> shared(new int(), [](int* i) {
    // Called immediately if using only tuple constructor!
  });
  return token(shared);
}
token my_token = make_token(); // std::shared_ptr<> is already gone!
```

Comment: works in gcc but not in clang

Comment: @Danh Thanks! I am not going crazy then. Who do I report this to?

Comment: Seems fixed on trunk (http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8YUeWAcj3PzyWphs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, your code should work fine, msvc and gcc seems to agree with me in [this snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c946165281fc914). From T.C. comment, this is looked like the real issue with clang and is fixed in clang trunk

As a workaround for now, I suggest this approach, (`special_decay_t` is taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
struct unwrap_refwrapper
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
struct unwrap_refwrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>>
{
    using type = T&;
};

template <class T>
using special_decay_t = typename unwrap_refwrapper<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type;

class token {
public:
  template<typename... Types>
  token(Types&&... types) : _self(std::make_shared<std::tuple<special_decay_t<Types>...>>(std::forward<Types>(types)...)) {}

private:
  std::shared_ptr<void> _self;
};


token make_token() {
  return token(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(), [](int* i) {
    std::cout << "freed\n";
    delete i;
  }));
}

int main()
{
    token my_token = make_token();
    std::cout << __LINE__ << '\n';
}
```

See this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d746ab06556d5e0)